# Assignment many variable separated by comma in one line. C#

Tags: c#, comma-operator

Sorry for this stupid question, but I can't find answer for it. So, why I can't write code like this in C#:

```
int a = 10, b = 20, c = 30, d = 40;    
a = b, c = d;
```

In C++ I can write it and it will be ok.

Why it doesn't compile in C#?

Comment: Why not just try: `int a = b, c = d;` if you want to get rid off of the values of a and c?

Comment: You write: a = b; c = d; in C#

Comment: @Surya I just want to clarified my quesion by example. Maybe it's not very good. But i try to focus on second line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *can* write the first line.  That is allowed in C#, and spelled out in section 8.5.1 of the C# Language Spec, where it shows that each *local-variable-declarator* can be in a list that's comma separated:

```
local-variable-declarators:
    local-variable-declarator
    local-variable-declarators   ,   local-variable-declarator
```

However, C# does not have a [comma operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) like C++, so you have to split the second line:

```
int a = 10, b = 20, c = 30, d = 40; 
a = b;
c = d;
```

Comment: Can you explain, what mean comma operator in C#?
Why i can initializate varibale by comma, write statements in for but can't write such code?

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin There is no comma operator in C#.  The only reason that's legal in C++ is that there is an operator in that language which allows multiple expressions to be placed where a single expression is expected (the C++ comma operator).  That operator doesn't exist in C# - it's just not part of the language.

Comment: Why i can write i = x, j = y in this code:
`for (int i = 0, j = 0;; i = x, j = y) {...}`
This is special design for "for"?

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin Yes - For loops allow a "statement-expression-list" (the list is key) in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Simply because C# is not C++, and the two languages are different from one another.

Or, more precisely: The C# language is not a superset of the C++ language. Therefore not every C++ program is a valid C# program.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is just fine. However, the second line consists of two separate statements. Statements have to be separated by a semicolon `;`.